# Why do I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error?

Tags: java, android

I have this code, I took it from stackoverflow and a bit changed it. The code  retrieve the gallery`s content and put every image path inside an array list. Then it choose randomly  one of the path inside the ArrayList and put as resources for an ImageView. Thank you for attention.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ImageView randomPicture;
    private Bitmap currentBitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        randomPicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.random_picture);
        final ArrayList<String> imagesPath = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
        };

        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images, projection, null, null, null)

        if(cur == null) {
            randomPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture);
        }
        else {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

                int dataColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                do {
                    imagesPath.add(cur.getString(dataColumn));
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
            cur.close();
            final Random random = new Random();
            final int count = imagesPath.size();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int number = random.nextInt(count);
                    String path = imagesPath.get(number);
                    if (currentBitmap != null)
                        currentBitmap.recycle();
                    currentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                    randomPicture.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes on the line with Cursor with the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.postcards, PID: 2424
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
at com.example.postcards.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:53)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: please tell me which line is **MainActivity.java:53**?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
int number = random.nextInt(count);
```

gives you the error because you pass 0 as the count. Using `nextInt(int)` requires input that is greater than 0. The input cannot be negative or 0

Answer (score 1):

`Random#nextInt(int)` expects the argument to be positive. This is not the case here.

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java#Random.nextInt%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that you cannot pass to `Random.nextInt()` method a value less or equal to 0.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the nextInt from random. It is possible that your count is zero?